# How can I generate and excel output from django python

Tags: python, django, excel

Given a query set from my database, I am trying to output the results into an excel file. I have tried two versions of code... the code executes properly without outputting any error messages, but the excel file is not outputted, any suggestions on where I went wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv, io, xlsxwriter
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, JsonResponse, FileResponse

def print_excel(request)
    products = Product.objects.all()
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(products.values()))
    excel_file = io.BytesIO()
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(xlwriter, 'sheetname')
    xlwriter.save()
    #xlwriter.close()
    excel_file.seek(0)

    response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/ms-excel vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    # set the file name in the Content-Disposition header
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.xls'
    return response
```

I also tried the below approached where I tried to output an excel with the string `rows`

```
import pandas as pd
import csv, io, xlsxwriter
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, JsonResponse, FileResponse

def print_excel(request)
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(buffer)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write('A1', "rows")
    workbook.close()
    buffer.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='myfile.xlsx')
```

The two codes executes properly but I cant locate the excel file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, the problem might be with the get request... If you are using a fetch request via JavaScript, you will the error. For the `Fileresponse` and `HttpResponse` to work properly and generate the required files ensure the get request is generate directly from the html template i,e use `<a href="">Generate Excel</a>`